# How to disable compression when building a ZIP archive with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a ZIP archive generated by maven-assembly-plugin.  It mostly contains JARs which are already compressed.  Compressing them again will only increase the build time without any gain.  How do I configure maven-assembly-plugin (or assembly descriptor) to turn off compression (i.e. store only) when building a ZIP archive?

Comment: With `zip` you can use option `-n .jar:.class`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `archiverConfig` element in the assembly plugin configuration, setting the `compress` option to `false`.

e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip-application.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <attach>true</attach>

        <!-- Turn off compression -->
        <archiverConfig>
            <compress>false</compress>
        </archiverConfig>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```